# Pivot UWP with PivotItems with views

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, mvvmcross, uwp-xaml

To get a clear view.
I am using MvvMCross with UWP.

The parent model

```
public class TabHost : MvxViewModel
{
    private IList<TabPage> _tabPages;
    public IList<TabPage> TabPages
    {
        get { return _tabPages; }
        set
        {
            _tabPages = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => TabPages);
        }
    }
}
```

TabPage object

```
public class TabPage
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public Type ViewModelType {get;set;}
}
```

I created an override of Pivot called TabControl so my xaml is this:

```
<controls:TabControl x:Name="TabHostControl" ItemsSource="{Binding TabPages}">
    <controls:TabControl.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TabControl.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame x:Name="ViewToLoad" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</controls:TabControl>
```

My tabpages with title is correctly shown. However I want the content of the view is loaded in the PivotItem.

- I tried while rendering to navigate in each item to the view but that
  didn't work.
- Also tried (while rendering) to set the content. I am able to create
  the view and bind the ViewModel, but when set the Content it only
  shows the name of the object and not the xaml controls.
- And tried with UserControls but each view has is own context so didn't work at all

Is it possible to set an view for an PivotItem? (using MvvmCross offcourse!)
Or push content though via format of the dataitem template?

Answer (score 0):

why are you using a frame?

You can use a ContentControl to show the page there is not easy way to do that.

I did it before using another frameworks but it could be similar:

You can use a ContentControl and Behaviors
In the Behavior just create a property it could be the name of the view page that you want to show inside, create the instance of the view in code and the viewmodel of the view, make the binding with the View and the ViewModel(using DataContext property) and finally inject this view in the Content of the ContentControl.

If you really want to use Frame the solution is very similar.

Comment: thx for your reply, I will give it an try tomorrow. Let you know if it works!